# Wordpress How do I search post by datepicker?

Tags: wordpress, date, search, filter

I'm working on the WordPress website I have my own search filter page, where I added the jquery datepicker, now I want to search post by datepicker?

**Html Code**

```
script>
$(function() {

   jQuery( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker({
       dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd"
   });
   $("#datepicker-13").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
</script>

<input type = "text" name="datefrom" class="form-control alertform" id = "datepicker-13">
```

**Wordpress Query**

```
$datefrom = $_POST['datefrom'];

if(!empty($datefrom) && $datefrom !=='')
{
   $args    = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' =>8,
   'paged' => $paged,
   'post_date'  => $datefrom,
   'post_status' => 'publish' 
    );
}
 $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Here The Solution Of It

```
$datefrom = $_POST['datefrom'];
$time  = strtotime($datefrom);
$day   = date('d',$time);
$month = date('m',$time);
$year  = date('Y',$time);

$args = array(

    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' =>8,
    'paged' => $paged,

'date_query' => array(
    array(
   'year'  => $year,
   'month' => $month,
   'day'   => $day,
),
),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your date into 'year', 'month' & 'date' as below before querying.

```
$datefrom = $_REQUEST['datefrom'];
$datefromsplit = explode("-", $datefrom);
$yearval = $datefromsplit[0];
$monthval = $datefromsplit[1];
$dateval = $datefromsplit[2];

if(!empty($datefrom) && $datefrom!='')
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'paged' => $paged,                      
        'year'  => $yearval,
        'monthnum' => $monthval,
        'day' => $dateval
    );
}
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

You can read more at [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters).